# class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, eclipse, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am getting the following message while running my java program. I see lots of suggestions to remove the JUNIT and try which works perfectly fine but impacting my RunnerClass(Below) at the same time. There are suggestions given in other posts but apparently none seems to be working in my case. Any assistance will be really appreciated.

RunnerClass:-

```
package HybridFrameWork;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src\\test\\java\\HybridFrameWork", glue={"HybridFrameWork"},plugin="html:reports")
public class RunnerFile {   
}
```

My Java program is:-

```
package ServiceTesting;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import HybridFrameWork.Variables;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import ServiceTesting.Authentication;

public class Forgotpassword {

    @Test(priority=1)
    @Given("^Headers in Json format along with valid token$")
    public static void Headers_in_Json_format_along_with_valid_token() throws Throwable {
        Authentication.userlogin();
        RequestSpecification Request=given().header("Authorization", "bearer "+Variables.getToken()).contentType(ContentType.JSON);
        Variables.setRequest(Request);
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    @When("^Approprite email address in request body$")
    public static void Approprite_email_address_in_request_body() throws Throwable {

        RequestSpecification Request=Variables.getRequest().when().body("{\"Email\":\"XXY@YZZ\"}");

        Variables.setRequest(Request);


    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    @And("^Trigger the valid end point of forgot password$")
    public static void Trigger_the_valid_end_point_of_forgot_password() throws Throwable {

        Response Response=(Response) Variables.getRequest().post("XX//YY//ZZ");
        Variables.setResponse(Response);

    }

    @Test(priority=4)
    @Then("^Validation of all the response details$")
    public static void Validation_of_all_the_response_details() throws Throwable {

        ValidatableResponse Response=Variables.getResponse().then().statusCode(200).content("message", equalTo("XXYYZZ"));


    }

}
```

Error Message:-

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:128)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:117)
    at ServiceTesting.Authentication.userlogin(Authentication.java:36)
    at ServiceTesting.Forgotpassword.Headers_in_Json_format_along_with_valid_token(Forgotpassword.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:420)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:385)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```